# Populate UITableView Custom Cell with NSMutableArray data - Swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, nsmutablearray, custom-cell

I am trying to populate a UITableView with some data that I have stored in an NSMutableArray (not sure if it should just be an Array?).

The table consists of a custom cell which I have designed in the Storyboard which I have given the identifier: courseCell

To try and populate the UITableView with my data in my NSMutableArray, I was using this tutorial: http://www.codingexplorer.com/getting-started-uitableview-swift/ however it gets to a point where they are populating the cells using "cellForRowAtIndexPath", but they are just using the default cell style and so do the following:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(textCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    let row = indexPath.row
    cell.textLabel?.text = swiftBlogs[row]

    return cell
}
```

But I am using a custom cell which has two labels.

I wasn't sure what to do, so I made an outlet for the labels and also the prototype cell:

```
@IBOutlet var coursesTableView: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var customCell: UITableViewCell!
@IBOutlet weak var courseNameLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var courseCodeLabel: UILabel!
```

I am a little lost and not sure how I can go through the cellForRowAtIndexPath function, loading in my NSMutableArray data into the two labels. Any help would be appreciated!

**NOTE: I am only new to StackOverflow to please let me know if I have not been clear enough.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a custom `UITableViewCell`, then you need to create a class for that custom cell (and connect the cell with the class in storyboard).

This tutorial explains very well how custom cells work: [LINK](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JG_AMY_gSDQ)

**Note:** Your problem is not with `NSMutableArray`, it's populating the custom cell.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you :) that video was very good (although it could have been more concise).